# Morphing line with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael, vector-graphics

Is it possible using the raphael.js or paper.js to draw a line with an arrow that moves with some animation morphing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but the short answer to your question is almost certainly yes.  I can only speak for RaphaelJS, but it's easy to tell Raphael to morph from one path to the other.  Consider [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/4JyKh/) fiddle and [that](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/MqFkP/2/) fiddle, both of which rely on using raphael's `animate` function to modify the `path` element over time, often in conjunction with one or more transforms.  The only caveat is that raphael's built-in path morphing doesn't always unwind in the way you might expect or desire.  But in an attempt to animate something like the figure above, I'd do something like this:

```
var canvas = Raphael( 0, 0, 320, 240 );

var path1 = "M0,120 h300 l10,-10 l10,10 h100";
var path2 = "M0,120 h100 l10,-10 l10,10 h300";

var path = canvas.path( path1 ).attr( { stroke: 'black', fill: 'none', 'stroke-width': 1 } );

path.animate( { path: path2, stroke: 'red', 'stroke-width': 3 }, 3000, function()
              { path.animate( { path: path1, stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 1 }, 3000 ); } );
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/LRmLH/).